# Is it prohibited to mock the LGBT community in France?

Tags: france, religion, freedom-of-speech

Recent question: [Freedom of speech and blasphemy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/59464/freedom-of-speech-and-blasphemy) caused me to think about it and ask myself:

**is there any limits/prohibits for mocking in France? Is it legal to criticize the LGBT community?**

As we see, it is legal to mock religions, but what else?

Comment: I'm migrating this to Law.SE because this seems to be a 'what is the law?' question rather than a question which falls within the scope of our site. As noted [here](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2703/28994), a law is not on-topic just because it's a matter of political discourse.

Comment: "LGBT" is not an organisation; so there's no organization policy either which could be subject to criticism. Pretending otherwise is setting up a straw man, often for hate speech. There are multiple organizations (with various degrees of overlap) which have LGBT members. It could be valid to ask whether such an organization can legally be criticized for its policy. (Spoiler: yes)

Comment: How does one "criticize LGBT"?

Comment: @MSalters "LGBT" refers to various conditions that manifest in particular actions. One can criticize those actions.

Comment: Before you draw any conclusions, think about the difference between criticising people based on they say or do, and criticising people based on what they are. You might have an _Eureka!_ moment if you do.

Comment: Such laws are subject to selective enforcement, depending on political expediency. Are you insulting someone the government wants to protect? Then it could lead to violence and you're clearly inciting violence. Are you openly threatening someone the government couldn't care less about? Here's your slap on the wrist, off you go.

Comment: @jcaron : one could certainly criticize LGBT people for how they choose to behave... is it then the former or the latter, according to your classification?

Comment: @vsz LGBT people don’t chose to be so. They are. This is verts offering from religion, which is a choice.

Comment: @jcaron : you completely missed my point. It's not about being LGBT vs not being LGBT (although we might debate about nature vs nurture, but that's not what I was aiming at). I was talking about behavior. For just one very rough example, I suppose you don't think parading naked through a city is something they "are", instead of something they choose to do so.

Comment: @vsz and some people will mock or criticise them for that, which is very different from mocking or criticising them for being what they are.

Comment: @jcaron quite the unsubstantiated (and minority) opinion, that Muslims for example "chose" their group and by implication the prejudice which follows, when LGBT did not. Almost every single religious person would disagree with that strange characterisation, just as gay people dispute the false characterisation that theirs is a "lifestyle choice"

Comment: @benxyzzy I fear we are straying far off-topic. By definition, faith is a choice. The fact that some communities (and even states) will try to force people into a religion (by declaring them as members of that religion at birth, preventing them from denouncing it, and forcing them to respect wherever rules are thought to be imposed by that religion) does not make it any less a choice to actually believe in it or not.

Answer (score 30):

### Mockery is allowed; hate speech isn’t

While freedom of speech is guaranteed under French law it does have [limits](https://www.gouvernement.fr/en/everything-you-need-to-know-about-freedom-of-expression-in-france). Since 2004, these limits have applied to gender and sexuality.

Mockery is contemptuous or insulting speech; hate speech or vilification incites hatred, serious contempt or ridicule. The boundary between them must be established on a case-by-case basis including both content and context (“I’m going to get you” can be a serious threat but it can also be what a father says to his child when chasing them in the park) but in France, as in other liberal democracies, the benefit of the doubt goes to speech being considered lawful.

Comment: Could you please provide two sentences as an example?

Comment: How is contemptuous speech allowed, but inciting contempt not? Isn't contemptuous speech advocating contempt?

Comment: That seems to be a very vague, if not nonexistent line between yes and no.

Comment: @Davor yes, that’s why we have judges and juries

Comment: @Acccumulation not all contempt is "serious" contempt

Comment: @EricDuminil Think of the gay guy, Damian, from the movie "Mean Girls" in these examples.
Mockery: "There's Damian, he's almost too gay to function"
Hate speech: "There's Damian, he's a great example of everything God hates about [epithet]s"

Comment: @DaleM: I don't think France has a jury trial for these cases.

Comment: To give specific examples: "Homosexuality is an abomination" => Not hate speech (after appeal to the Supreme Court *cour de cassassion*) https://tetu.com/2018/01/10/christine-boutin-acquittee-ou-commence-incitation-a-la-haine/
"AIDS: Despite risks, they will give you their blood" => Hate speech (https://www.rtl.fr/actu/justice-faits-divers/homophobie-minute-condamne-pour-incitation-a-la-haine-7772140701)

Comment: @DaleM - yes, we had those in my ex-communist country, too. Wanna guess how it worked out?

Comment: @Davor shall we say independent and impartial judges and juries then?

Comment: @DaleM - eh, we may as well say unicorns then.

Answer (score 14):

**Mocking, or criticising homosexuality, or LGBT as a concept is OK**. For example, former governement member Christine Boutin said "Homosexuality is an abomination", and [it was considered OK](https://tetu.com/2018/01/10/christine-boutin-acquittee-ou-commence-incitation-a-la-haine/) (after appeals, she lost in lower courts, but eventually prevailed).

**Mocking, or criticising LGBT people is not**. For example, [far right magazine "Minute" got a 7.000€ fine](https://www.rtl.fr/actu/justice-faits-divers/homophobie-minute-condamne-pour-incitation-a-la-haine-7772140701) for a front page saying "AIDS: Despite risks, they will give you their blood".

Same goes for religion. Criticising a religion is OK, criticising folks practising this religion is not (caricatures vs. saying ["muslims must choose between Islam and France"](https://www.leparisien.fr/faits-divers/eric-zemmour-definitivement-condamne-pour-provocation-a-la-haine-contre-les-musulmans-19-09-2019-8155785.php))

Comment: That headline goes far beyond merely mocking or criticising, it's a blatant accusation of immoral and probably criminal behavior. Accusing someone of being a pedophile or bank robber is also not mere mockery.